# How do I output raw html when using RazorEngine (NOT from MVC)

Tags: c#, razor, html-encode

I am trying to generate emails with HTML content.  this content has already gone through sanitation so I am not worried in that regard, however when I call:

```
Razor.Parse(template, model);
```

on the following Razor template:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <body>
        @(new System.Web.HtmlString(Model.EmailContent))
    </body>
</html>
```

the email that is outputted is HTMl encoded, but I need it decoded.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I answered this, but it was deleted as a duplicate answer because I answered it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603593/razorengine-cannot-use-html-raw ... this answer works for both MVC and RazorEngine.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

RazorEngine, like MVC's Razor View Engine, will automatically encode values written to the template. To get around this, we've introduce an interface called `IEncodedString`, with the default implementations being `HtmlEncodedString` and `RawString`.

To use the latter, simply make a call to the inbuilt `Raw` method of `TemplateBase`:

```
@Raw(Model.EmailContent)
```

Comment: @Matthew Sorry for reviving, but even though this compiles, it does not look pretty in the VS HTML Editor, it wont recognize Model or Raw anymore. Any workarounds?

Comment: @Jeff I'm thinking the right approach is for RazorEngine to expose a static class Html.cs that has a static method .Raw so that it will process standard calls to Html.Raw that can be used to get correct syntax highlighting in VS Razor editor.

Comment: @Manfred @Raw() works fine in RazorEngine (not ASP.NET MVC's Razor ;) )

Comment: Would like to see this solved too. This causes the whole project not to build with MvcBuildViews enabled...

Comment: The "HtmlEncodedString" doesnt work! Instead use: RawString.
See an example that works!

public RazorEngine.Text.IEncodedString GetMarcaFinalDocumento()
{ return new RazorEngine.Text.RawString("<div>Hi there!</div>");}

Answer (score 17):

FYI I have a fork that includes the @Html.Raw(...) syntax here:

https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/pull/105

Comment: @Html.Raw() required no upfront configuration. Good solution.

Comment: Me too. I was able to generated HTML tags and values in Razor Code and pass it to View with ViewData and display using @Html.Ras(ViewData["NextEvent"]

Answer (score 6):

I am using RazorEngine 3.8.2 and `@Raw(Model.Content)` is working perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a custom base class for your templates, you can code `Write` method to behave similar to normal MVC template: if the output value is `IHtmlString` it should not encode it.

Here's the code I'm using in my `TemplateBase` class:

```
// Writes the results of expressions like: "@foo.Bar"
public virtual void Write(object value)
{
    if (value is IHtmlString)
        WriteLiteral(value);
    else
        WriteLiteral(AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(value.ToString(), false));
}

// Writes literals like markup: "<p>Foo</p>"
public virtual void WriteLiteral(object value)
{
    Buffer.Append(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Built a wrapper for RazorEngine that adds in support for `@Html.Raw()` and `@Html.Partial()`

https://github.com/b9chris/RazorEngineComplete