# RazorEngine: cannot use Html.Raw

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, razorengine

using RazorEngine outside asp.net I'm experiencing this error when I try to write raw html by using `@Html.Raw("html string here")`:

> Unable to compile template. The name 'Html' does not exist in the current context

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is this downvoted? This question helped me.

Comment: Probably because people assume its a standard razor question not the engine.

Answer (score 31):

The solution has been found here: https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/34

It's enough to use `@(new RawString("html string here"))` or `@Raw("html string here")` instead of `@Html.Raw("html string here")`.

I hope this helps!
Bye

Comment: Neither of these work with dotnet 5 anymore.

Comment: It works (with aspnet 4.x) but the the cshtml still cry a "CS0103 The name 'Raw' does not exist in the current context" fake error.

Answer (score 6):

I implemented my own Raw whose result implements both IHtmlString and IEncodedString... and it worked! :)

```
In my csthml:
@MyRazorParser.Raw("<b>Testing</b>")
```

This works both when MVC uses it *and* when the RazorEngine parser uses it.

```
public class MyRawResult : RazorEngine.Text.IEncodedString, System.Web.IHtmlString
{
    public string Value;
    public MyRawResult(string value) { Value = value; }
    public string ToEncodedString()
    {
        return Value;
    }

    public string ToHtmlString()
    {
        return Value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value;
    }
}

public static class MyRazorParser
{
    public static object Raw(string str)
    {
        return new MyRawResult(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case my _ViewImports.cshtml file was missing a reference to:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
```

Once I added this ff8mania's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with RazorLight not being able to handle @Html.Raw calls in partial views. I just made a Utility class with a Raw method and used that instead.

```
public static IHtmlContent Raw(string? str)
    {
        return new HtmlString(str);
    }
```

This works because my namespace is already being injected into the RazorLight engine.

```
private RazorLightEngine engine = new RazorLightEngineBuilder()
        .UseFileSystemProject(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString())
        .AddDefaultNamespaces("MyCoolProject.Models")
        .UseMemoryCachingProvider()
        .Build();
```

Then replace `@Html.Raw(Model.HtmlString)` with `@Utility.Raw(Model.HtmlString)` and you're ducky.