# Generate html in body with RazorEngine email template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razorengine

I'm using [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) to generate an email with a template.

The issue I'm having is I cannot add a line break in the email body.

```
var model = new EmailModel
        {
            Destination = "anon@gmail.com",
            Subject = "Some Subject",
            Body = "Hello <br> Break <br> it <br> up"
        };

var service = TemplateManager.RazorService;
var htmlBody = service.RunCompile("EmailTemplate.cshtml", model.GetType(), model);
await EmailService.SendEmail(model.Destination, model.Subject, htmlBody);
```

I tried doing the following in my Template:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Body)
```

But it still won't decode the html, any ideas?

Comment: What kind of HTML strings returned by `RunCompile` method in `htmlBody`? Also show your `EmailTemplate.cshtml` content code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

The solution has been found here: https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/34

And here: [RazorEngine: cannot use Html.Raw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603593/razorengine-cannot-use-html-raw)

> It's enough to use @(new RawString("html string here")) or @Raw("html
>   string here") instead of @Html.Raw("html string here").

Answer (score 1):

Your `<br>` tag in the Body is incorrect.

Replace `<br>` with `<br />`