# Render Html code from a property using FluentMail in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, email, .net-core

I am using the FluentMail for sending emails from template in .Net Core.
There is a problem when using it, because one property is a string where I store HTML, the problem that instead of processing the HTML, it is printing it like

```
<p> this is a text </p>
```

instead of

```
this is a text
```

The code is basically like:

```
var inviteEmailViewModel = new InviteEmailViewModel(_emailAppSettings.EmailInviteSubject,
               requester.Name,
               roleName,
               entityType,
               entityName,
               invitationUrl,
               registrationUrl,
               textPreview,
               text);

            var inviteEmailPath = $"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}{_emailAppSettings.EmailInvitePath}";

            List<Address> adresses = emailsTo.Select(x => new Address() { EmailAddress = x }).ToList();

            var sendResponse = await _fluentEmail
               .To(adresses)
               .Subject(_emailAppSettings.EmailInviteSubject)
               .UsingTemplateFromFile(inviteEmailPath, inviteEmailViewModel)
               .SendAsync();
```

The `InviteEmailViewModel` has the `string` property **Text**

And the template is defined as below

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>@Model.Text</td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**How can I render the HTML that is passed on the string, instead of printing it as a string?**

I already tried something like `@Html.Raw`, but it throws an exception on FluentMail.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23603594/8391028

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>@Raw(Model.Text)</td> 
    </tr>
</tbody>
```