# Razor engine display angle brackets in markdown

Tags: c#, razor, templating

I'm trying to parse a markdown-string:

My model is something like this:

```
class Model
{
    public string MethodName {get;set;}
    public string CodeBlock {get;set;}
}
```

json-data of my model:

```
{
    "MethodName":"Test",
    "CodeBlock":"int[] s = new List<int>().ToArray();"
}
```

my template looks like this:

````
string template = @"# @Model.MethodName

```csharp
@Model.CodeBlock
```";
````

I'm parsing with:

```
string generatedCode = Razor.Parse(template, model);
```

the parsed output now looks like:

````
# Test

```csharp
int[] s = new List&lt;int&gt;().ToArray();
```
````

So the engine parses `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;` (instead of leaving it with those brackets), which is not correct displayed in a markdown-editor.
What I really want to get is:

````
# Test

```csharp
int[] s = new List<int>().ToArray();
```
````

Any idea what I could do to get this?

Comment: Use `@Html.Raw(...)` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105587/how-does-html-raw-mvc-helper-work

Comment: @Lanorkin thx but this is not MVC, this is just templating with the Razor-Engine in a console-application. `@Html` is undefined here.

Comment: They have `@Raw` helper for that see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661180/how-do-i-output-raw-html-when-using-razorengine-not-from-mvc

Comment: Thanks @Lanorkin that's what I searched for but didn't find.